# WPF WebBrowser Mouse Events not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, mouseevent

I have a WebBrowser object in a WPF Page and I'm trying to do something whenever the user interacts with the page. I have intially tried to use the events associated with the WebBrowser object but they don't seem to be firing. Below is a simplified example of what my code is trying to do:

```
webBrowser.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(webBrowser_MouseDown);
```

with the event handler as:

```
void webBrowser_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Pressed");
}
```

However when I run the page and click inside the WebBrowser no message box is displayed.

Apologies, originally I had mentioned that it was a System.Controls WebBrowser rather than a Forms browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mouse events are not supported by the `WebBrowser` control, [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_members.aspx). You need to hook up handlers to the DOM events provided by the document being displayed in the control, using the `WebBrowser.Document` property. [This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/6f292ac0-ccbf-4fc1-88a5-e3b9ea8d862a) has an example of how to do this.

Comment: This put me on the right track. Similar procedure: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=312777

Comment: It's also helpful to checkout: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/393.aspx if you plan to use the browser while handling events!

Comment: Take a look at my post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805833/inspect-element-from-my-wpf-webbrowser-using-inspect-elementsie-chrome-fir/30919955#30919955) I had the same problems for the old winforms webbrowser control(included in WPF) and the normal wpf webbrowser control. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

Add the ms html com library

Once the WebBrowser.LoadCompleted event fires try this:

```
mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event doc = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)Browser.Document);
doc.onmouseover += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_onmouseoverEventHandler(doc_onmouseover);
```

or use some other event.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: * Once we refresh the page the attached event gets removed.