# How to use 'Back' & 'Forward' navigation button events in WPF WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

The `WebBrowser` control in WPF is inherited from the`UIElement`, but we cannot register event handlers in `UIElement` events. Why is it? At [WPF WebBrowser Mouse Events not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189510/wpf-webbrowser-mouse-events-not-working-as-expected), it is answered but I still cannot understand.

Anyway, hooking up handlers to the events provided by the document of the `WebBrowser` can catch most mouse events but cannot use 'Back' & 'Forward' navigation button events. Since the internet explorer can do this, I think it is possible. Is there any way to solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**
In this question, `'Back' & 'Forward' navigation buttons`mean XButton1 and XButton2 in 5-button mouse system.

**UPDATE2:** I fixed this question with the Navid Rahmani's answer. I'd think someone will need this answer, so I attach main part. If finding any problem or more reasonable solution, please let me know.

```
    //This code assumes the `WebBrowser` field named _webBrowser is already initiated.
    //For the detail out of this code, please refer to the Navid Rahmani's answer.

    private bool _isMouseOver;
    private HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event _docEvent;    

    public ctor()
    {
        _webBrowser.LoadCompleted += _webBrowser_LoadCompleted;
    }

    private void _webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_docEvent != null)
        {
            _docEvent.onmouseover -= _docEvent_onmouseover;
            _docEvent.onmouseout -= _docEvent_onmouseout;
        }
        if (_webBrowser.Document != null)
        {
            _docEvent = (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)_webBrowser.Document;
            _docEvent.onmouseover += _docEvent_onmouseover;
            _docEvent.onmouseout += _docEvent_onmouseout;
        }
    }

    void _docEvent_onmouseout(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
    {
        _isMouseOver = false;
    }

    void _docEvent_onmouseover(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
    {
        _isMouseOver = true;
    }


    private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (_isMouseOver)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && (MouseMessages)wParam == MouseMessages.XBUTTON)
            {
                var hookStruct = (Msllhookstruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(Msllhookstruct));
                if (hookStruct.mouseData == 0x10000)
                {
                    //do something when XButto1 clicked
                }
                else if (hookStruct.mouseData == 0x20000)
                {
                    //do something when XButto2 clicked
                }
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }


    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        //WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1,
        //WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        //WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        //WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        //WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        //WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205,
        XBUTTON = 0x020B,
    }
```

Comment: No problem. It's fixed through your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **low level hook of mouse** and check if the xbutton1 or xbutton2 clicked
look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx)

for the value of `WM_XBUTTONDOWN` look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646245(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I tried as your answer, but the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`event was cool and the `XBUTTON`event was not. I tried `0x0001 and 0x0020`as the value of `MouseMessages enum`for the `XBUTTON`event. I made something wrong?

Comment: did you checked the high order text? look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997498.aspx

Comment: No you should check `0x020C` and for button check high order word parameter `0x0001` and `0x0002`

Comment: I would like to thank for your comment. I achieved the use of the mouse navigation events with `0x020B` as the `MouseMessages enum` and, `0x10000` for the left `XBUTTON` and  `0x20000` for the right `XBUTTON` as the `hookStruct.mouseData`. However, the mouse navigation events is handled if the events is fired anywhere in the windows.

Comment: You can check if the mouse is over the document.

Comment: Is there any way only the events are handled in the target region of my main view?

Comment: use one of these `(UIElement)Mouse.DirectlyOver;` or `element.IsMouseOver`

Comment: I fixed all of this issue. Thanks a lot. I'll give you the bounty after the limitation time. I couldn't use the `IsMouseOver` of the WebBrowser directly, which is the same problem  with this question. So, I used the `HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event.onmouseover&onmouseout` events to set the mouse over state.

Answer (score 4):

Much simpler way....

This works for me in WPF and .net 4.5

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
if (e.ChangedButton.Equals(MouseButton.XButton1)) MessageBox.Show(@"back");
if (e.ChangedButton.Equals(MouseButton.XButton2)) MessageBox.Show(@"forward");
}
```

Comment: The MouseDown and PreviewMouseDown are swallowed by the WebBrowser control, so it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser controll is really just thin wrapper around the Trident COM object.  It's not 'pure WPF' like other built-in controls... so lots of normal things don't work with it.  To answer your question, the closest you can get is hooking into the Navigating event.  This won't tell you whether the user is trying to go forwards or back or elsewhere but it will give you the URL and the opportunity to set e.Cancel = true to stop the navigation (usually followed by calling Navigate(url) to take the user somewhere else).

Comment: First, I would like to thank for your answer. However, regardless of a direction, I cannot register a event handle to the navigating event of the `WebBrowser` with the mouse `XButton` click.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Install my nuget package [Lette.Wpf.AppCommands](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lette.Wpf.AppCommands/) ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/Lette/Lette.Wpf.AppCommands)) and add this to your main window:

```
<l:Window.AppCommandBindings>
    <AppCommandBinding AppCommand="BrowserBackward" Command="{Binding BackCommand}" />
</l:Window.AppCommandBindings>
```

The `BackCommand` will be invoked whenever the "back" button (whichever it is) is pressed.

### Explanation

The `XButton1` and `XButton2` may default to being mapped to *Back* and *Forward* navigation, *but this may not always be the case*. Those buttons can be remapped to other functions, and some mice have more than five buttons. So, how do you actually listen for the *Backwards navigation* message?

1. Hook up a `WndProc`.
2. Listen for the [`WM_APPCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-appcommand) message.
3. In the `lparam`, do some bit-twiddling and find the actual `APPCOMMAND_*` value.
4. If it is the desired value (eg. `APPCOMMAND_BROWSER_BACKWARD`), do your thing.

Example:

```
var hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(mainWindow).Handle);
hwndSource.AddHook(WndProc);

// ...

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == WM_APPCOMMAND)
    {
        var appCommand = BitTwiddling(lparam);

        if (appCommand == APPCOMMAND_BROWSER_BACKWARD)
        {
            // do your thing
        }
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

The `mainWindow` is a reference to your main window (of type `Window`).

The `BitTwiddling` is basically: convert the `IntPtr` to an `int`, shift right 16 bits then mask with 0x7FFF.