# Mouse extra buttons in WPF

Tags: wpf, mouseevent

Is it possible to capture clicks from the extra buttons of a mouse in WPF? I want to implement back and forward navigation using the mouse in my application like when you browse the Internet. When an extra button is clicked I want to execute a command. I have only managed to find examples where the left/right/wheel buttons are used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371477/how-to-use-back-forward-navigation-button-events-in-wpf-webbrowser

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I just need to execute my commands when the appropriate button is clicked.

Comment: Added an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69612409/11808

Answer (score 5):

In the constructor:

```
  MouseDown += MouseDownEvent;
```

The event handler:

```
  private void MouseDownEvent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
        switch (e.ChangedButton)
        {
             case MouseButton.XButton1://Back button
                MessageBox.Show("Back button pressed");
                break;
             case MouseButton.XButton2://forward button
                MessageBox.Show("Forward button pressed");
                break;
             default:
                break;
        }
  }
```