# Disabling Context Menu on PDF viewer over Webbrowser

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I'm trying to disable the right click(well context menu) on a PDF file over a webbrowser UIElement. But no matter what it never calls to the desired handler (same behavior with a webbrowser loading usual html, but not with other UIElements).

```
    public override UIElement Play()
    {
        base.Play();

        //It will be represented in a Webbrowser element
        WebBrowser element = new WebBrowser();

        element.ContextMenuOpening +=new ContextMenuEventHandler(element_ContextMenuOpening);

        //navigate to the current path of the file in the HDD, adding some parameters to avoid the Adobe Reader pannels to be shown
        element.Source = new Uri(path+"#toolbar=0&navpanes=0");
        return element;
    }

    public void element_ContextMenuOpening(Object obj, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CONTEXT MENU PDF");
    }
```

The "CONTEXT MENU PDF" line is never printed. I have also tried with MouseDown, but remains the same.

EDIT 1: Thanks to MephestoKhaan I managed to make this work with Webs over webbrowser. For PDF it should be something similar and I'm still looking for the correct class to cast the Webbrowser.document object to.

```
    public override UIElement Play()
    {
        base.Play();

        //the element will be represented in a webbroser
        element = new WebBrowser();
        //load the web indicated by the path (url)
        element.NavigateToString(Path);
        element.Source = new Uri(Path);

        //disable context menu
        mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event iEvent;
        iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event) element.Document;
        iEvent.oncontextmenu += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_oncontextmenuEventHandler(iEvent_oncontextmenu); 


        return element;
    }

    bool iEvent_oncontextmenu(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, MephestoKhaan's is the correct approach for elements over webbrowsers (in it's example: webs) but after struggling with Acrobat Reader over Webbrowser I changed to Foxit Reader.

with Foxit I can disable all menus and right click events directly on preferences and open it in fullscreen (not a webbrowser but a different window). It's not exactly what I was asking but solved my deppest problem (no context menu on a PDF viewer).

For the records> If you want to have buttons or some custom interface over a window use a Popup and set the windows to be over everything.

Comment: Hi, may i know how u disable all the menu and right click event by using FoxIt? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=312777 (from here [WPF WebBrowser Mouse Events not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189510/wpf-webbrowser-mouse-events-not-working-as-expected=). It seems that the WPF itself doesn´t manage the controls, so you have to bound the handler to the document.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great with webpages, but still no luck for PDF over webbrowser. I need to find the correct class to cast the .Document and then register the handler