# Hide cursor wpf WebBrowser control?

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer

neither

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="wbMain" Cursor="None"></WebBrowser>
```

nor

```
*{cursor:none}
```

is working for me.  I can't find any resources online telling me how to accomplish this.  The use-case for this is an application that runs full screen meant for viewing only after the setup takes place.

Edit: I forgot to add that the css works as expected when viewing the website in the IE9 browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good or bad practice but you can add System.Windows.Forms reference

then

```
private void MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide();
        }

        private void MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Show();
        }
```

use this code on mouseEnter form example in web-browser control

Comment: I believe there are no mouse event handlers with the web browser control ->

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189510/wpf-webbrowser-mouse-events-not-working-as-expected

Comment: _however_, the System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide works like a charm.  I still have to figure out a method to make it hide upon timer logic, but that should be simple.

fyi - the supposedly correct way to hide the cursor in wpf applications is the following: Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;  Note that this doesn't work - for the reason I had wrongly assumed was the browser taking control of the cursor.

Comment: any who glad you found what you want

Comment: Yeah - I spent far too long on this.  Thanks much for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

For those who dont like to add WinForms reference, try

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int ShowCursor(bool bShow);
```

and call ShowCursor(false) when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In app.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{

    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide();

}
```