# How to make a messagebox show up on left click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a pretty simple problem but I can't get it to work. I want a `MessageBox` to appear each time I left click inside my form. I didn't know how to capture it on the whole form so I started of trying to capture my left click inside my `WebBrowser1`. However, nothing really happens when trying to trigger the event.

I declared the action as `WebBrowser1_Mousedown`.

```
private void WebBrowser1_Mousedown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }

 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

My  relevant XAML as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="IndianBrowser.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="488.806" Width="807.089" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
```

and now trying with the webbrowser:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowser1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto"    Margin="0,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" MouseDown="WebBrowser1_Mousedown"/>
```

Comment: AS you're using WPF, you're most likely hosting the webbrowser in another XAML element (window at least) so maybe you can catch the event on that control and see on what control the event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks, of course I can capture the event in the whole XAML window. But the problem still persists. Nothing simply happens.

Comment: @Djerry I'm trying to use the `private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)` but the messagebox doesn't show up when I try to trigger it.

Comment: Can you share your XAML, so to see which controls you use?

Comment: Sure, added relevant info in the main post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF WebBrowser Mouse Events not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189510/wpf-webbrowser-mouse-events-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation for `WebBrowser` class, you'll see that mouse events are not supported. What you can do instead is subscribe for [`HtmlDocument.MouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.mousedown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

**Update**

---

Here is small snippet that demonstrates how to do this in WPF, *NOTE* you will have to add reference to `Microsoft.mshtml` assembly:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.webBrowser1.Navigated += webBrowser1_Navigated;
    this.webBrowser1.Source = new Uri("your url");
}

void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    HTMLDocumentClass document = this.webBrowser1.Document as HTMLDocumentClass;
    document.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onclick += document_HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onclick;
}

bool document_HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onclick(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
{
    // here you can check if the clicked element is your form
    // if (pEvtObj.fromElement.id == "some id")
    MessageBox.Show("test");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't get the `HtmlElementEventArgs` as posted in your link to work. Could you show an example? My initial problem of wanting to capture my whole form still persists. Is it possible to do by making a transparent rectangle? Maybe it's possible to use the `MouseButtonEventArgs` then?

Comment: @proah, I've updated the answer, please take a look.

Comment: I get the error `Interop type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.`

Comment: Select `Microsoft.mshtml` reference in Solution Explorer and set 'Embed Interop Types' in Properties window to `False`.

Comment: Additional question, is it possible to do the same thing but with `hover`?

Comment: Check `HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onmouseover` event of the `HTMLDocumentClass`.