# VB.NET - Mouse Events for Notification Window with Webbrowser Control

Tags: vb.net, notifications, mouseevent, webbrowser-control

In VB.Net we're showing a small notification window (similar to Outlook new mail notification feature), whenever a content (may be jobs completed in past few minutes along with some statistics) of a website changes. The data to be shown is a small table, so we're using webbrowser control (docked on top of the windows form) to render the html in a table format. However we're not able to use MouseEnter, MouseMove, MouseMove events, to keep the notification window alive when user navigates on top of the window.

Is there anyway where we can have this resolved? We somehow need to trigger a event whenever the mouse stays on the notification window.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Please post some code or a list of settings for your form.

Comment: I did had tried. When only windows form is there it works perfectly. But when WebBrowser is added & docked to the form, its not recognizing any of the mouse events.

Comment: So instead of docking the control, I tried to give a small space around all the borders. Now mouse enter event getting triggered when mouse enters the from but immediately mouse leave event gets triggered when it enters the webbrowser. The same way when the mouse is coming out of webbrowser it triggers mouse enter event & then it triggers mouse leave event when it comes out of the form. So I am not able to do anything when the mouse is resting on top of the webbrowser control.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now.  You will only be able to receive the `MouseMove` (etc.) events for the form when the mouse is over the form itself.  As you have discovered, the `WebBrowser` doesn't support the mouse events.  I've had a quick look and there's not an easy way around it - perhaps someone with more time on their hands could tell you how to forcefully add a window-wide mouse move event?  (I say someone - Google might be that someone...)

Comment: Or of course a simple click to the right of this comment yielded [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189510/wpf-webbrowser-mouse-events-not-working-as-expected?rq=1)...

Comment: Thanks Grim. I'd tried requesting help from google, but not much luck. Anyway I'll continue my analysis and will check the link you'd shared. Plz let me know in case if you have any other idea or suggestion that would help me.