# WPF Browser control Mousedown event not firing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I have a problem in my wpf project. I have a webbrowser control. What I want is to know whether anybody has clicked on the webrowser control. I used the mousedown event. But to my surprise it is not firing the event. In the webbrowser control I find that only Navigated and Navigating events are fired. Please let me know how can I get mousedown event? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189510/wpf-webbrowser-mouse-events-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by injecting javascript that adds a html mousedown event to the website. The javascirpt in turn invokes a wpf function that is written into a class using ComVisible[true].

http://sekhartechblog.blogspot.in/2012/04/webbrowser-javascript-communication-in.html

Answer (score 2):

Mouse events are not supported by the WebBrowser control. Please refer to the following (duplicate) question for more information about how you could solve this.

[WPF WebBrowser Mouse Events not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189510/wpf-webbrowser-mouse-events-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 1):

MACMAN, add event handler manually, like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
AddHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(WebBrowser_MouseDown), true);
```

ps: See this topic: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61807025-d4c4-41e0-b648-b11183065009/mousedown-event-not-working-wpf?forum=wpf